# получение паролей из Vault

Tags: python, aiogram, vault

мне предоставили токен к Vault, где хранится токен телеграмм-бота и не только.

я подключаюсь так:

```
client = hvac.Client(url='', token='')
```

затем в соответствии с документацией я пытаюсь получить этот токен телеграмм бота:

```
client.secrets.kv.v1.read_secret(
    path=secret_path,
    mount_point=mount_point)
```

ввожу путь в path и в точку входа mount_point ввожу название, под которым лежит токен телеграмм бота,
мне просто возвращается ответ 200.

Я совершенно не могу понять, как заставить python пойти в vault взять там токен бота и далее с ним работать.

Ошибка соответственно в том, что телеграмм ожидает токен бота, а я ему передаю класс Response/

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как именно мне взять информацию с Vault для дальнейшего использования

Comment: что именно нужно вводить в path, а что именно нужно вводить в  mount_point

Comment: в общем я нашла ответ на свой вопрос/ в url вводим до 8200 путь включительно. Далее у меня была папка1 в ней папка2 и только в папке2 были все данные. В path я ввела  имя папки2, а в mount_point имя папки1 и все заработало.